# Create independent process in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, process, fork, posix

I'm looking to implement a function similar to [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but on Linux. I did a lot of research and found the ["Fork off and die"](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Fork_off_and_die) approach which uses a double fork to run the child under init. That is, allow the child to operate independent of the parent.

Because the parent needs to return information about the newly created child process (i.e. pid, name, etc.) I need to know if I'm running into a race condition in my code. Currently, I fork and retrieve the second fork's pid via pipes then wait for the first fork to exit.

```
int child = 0;
int fd[2] = { 0, 0 };

if (pipe (fd) != 0)
    return Process();

int pid = fork();
if (pid < 0)
    return Process();

if (pid == 0) // Child
{
    if (setsid() != -1)
    {
        child = fork();
        if (child == 0)
        {
            umask (0); // Reset umask
            close (0); // Close stdin
            close (1); // Close stdout
            close (2); // Close stderr

            execvp ( ... );
            _exit (0);
        }

        // Do I need waitpid (child) here?
    }

    // Write the child PID using the pipe
    write (fd[1], &child, sizeof (child));
    _exit (0);
}

else // Parent
{
    // Read the child PID using the pipe
    read (fd[0], &child, sizeof (child));

    // Remove zombie process
    waitpid (pid, nullptr, 0);

    // Child must finish exec by this point

    return Process (child);
        // Also gets name
}
```

**Questions:**

- Do I need a second waitpid to wait for the child to finish the exec?
- Does waitpid return upon a call to exec?
- Does waitpid return even if exit or exec were called before waitpid?

Comment: Why do you want to double-fork? Double-forking is done when the new process should not be a child of the original process, quite the opposite of what you want to do.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. I want to create a process that has nothing to do with the parent process. So even when the parent dies the child continues. I return the child's PID so that I can debug it later if I wanted to. This is what the CreateProcess function does on Windows and I need to replicate it on Linux.

Comment: In the double-forking approach, the new process is *not* a child of the original process. You can't have cake and eat it, too, unless you hack something in a horrible fashion.

Comment: Why do you want to create a process that is not the child of your original process anyway?

Comment: I know it's not a child. I don't want it to be a child I want it to be independent, running off Init. I'm launching a daemon here. This new process will be just like any other process, I will be able to "attach" to it like I can any remote process. This is a remote process analysis library I'm building here.

Comment: As I said, hack something. For instance, you could use a pipe between the intermediate process and the original process to send the process id. You could also use shared memory for that. Notice that double forking is implemented by `daemon()`.

Comment: "So even when the parent dies the child continues." a child process continues when its parent dies. The "fork-off-and-die" method you're using works because of that. The only issue is that if it both becomes stopped (via SIGSTOP, SIGSTP or indirectly via C+Z) and its process group becomes orphaned (nonreachable from a different process group within the same session -- typically happens when your session leader  (typically your controlling terminal) dies), your stopped process will get sent SIGHUP and SIGCONT. SIGHUP typically kills you but you can ignore that signal or handle it differently.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to `waitpid()` on the second child. When a process's parent dies, the child will be adopted by the `init` process, so there will not be a zombie process.

`waitpid()` only returns after the child it waits on exits. A call to `execvp()` in the child means the waiter waits until the program that was executed dies, since that is when the child would die.

`waitpid()` will get the exit status of the process. It doesn't matter when the process actually exited.

Comment: But with the current code, the way I understand it is there's a chance that the returned Process could be executed before (or during) the call to exec. I need to guarantee that the waitpid only returns when the exec has concluded.

Comment: If you want to wait for the `execvp()` of the child to finish, don't do the double `fork()`.

Answer (score 0):

(A little clarification: what you're calling child, is actually your grandchild. It's the child of the process that just forked off and died.)

> > Do I need a second waitpid to wait for the child to finish the exec?

You can't. It's your grandchild and you can only wait on your direct children. Additionally, because your grandchild's parent has died, your grandchild has now been reparented to init (so it's actually your ex-grandchild).

> > Does waitpid return upon a call to exec?

Waitpid returns when the given pid dies/exits or immediately if it's already a zombie. The exec is called in the grandchild. Your waitpid calls are not at all not concerned with processes that aren't your direct children (unless you're using the Linux-only child-subreaper feature).

> > Does waitpid return even if exit or exec were called before waitpid?

Waitpid only ever returns when the waited on pid (which must be your direct child) is dead. If that's not yet the case, it will block.

Comment: True that I can't call waitpid on the grandchild but if you look at the code, my second waitpid would be right after the second fork. That is, the child would waitpid on the grandchild but you're saying exec wouldn't trigger that. Also what about the race condition. What if the returned Process gets executed before the exec call?

Comment: If you still care about your grandchild inasmuch as you want to wait on it and have a reliable* reference to it, you should have made it your child rather than disown it via double forking. (*Unless a process with certain pid is your child, you can't use that pid as a reliable reference to it because processes come and go and their pids get recycled).