# Need to start an independent program from within a program, c++ linux

Tags: c++, linux

I need to start a program from within a c++ program on linux, similar to what ShellExecute does on Windows. This program has to keep running even after the first program ends.

I found suggestions to use fork() and exec(), however these do not work for me as they create a child process that terminates when the parent process ends. I need to keep the new process running even after the parent has ended. Using system("") i have similar issues.

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();

char *arg[] = {"/home/pi/Robot/RobotUpdate", 0};

if (pid == 0)
    execv("/home/pi/Robot/RobotUpdate", arg);
```

/home/pi/Robot/RobotUpdate is a c++ program that has to keep running after the first program has ended.

EDIT:
solved with nohup command: system("nohup /home/pi/Robot/RobotUpdate &");

Comment: Hello @Tau, Welcome to S.O. Do you want to have a parent process that does not ends when the child process is finished??

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla no OP wants child process to continue when parent dies.

Comment: _"however these do not work for me as they create a child process that terminates when the parent process ends"_ I'm not convinced by this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200126/create-independent-process-in-linux?rq=1#comment48554310_30200126

Comment: You can run shild process through `nohup` utility or implement what nohup does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it may terminate when termination of parent leading to close of control terminal (or vice versa).

Comment: Yeah we're going to need more context/information from the OP

Comment: How you start child process using ```system()``` system call? You should start child process in background, and if the child process doesn't end by it's normal flow of execution then child process will not end on the end of parent process.

Comment: `fork` and `execve` *are* the way to go – there is yet another system call necessary to achieve the desired behaviour, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9038037/1312382) or [here](https://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2012/03/daemon-izing-process-in-linux.html).

Comment: Have a look at [daemon function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) as well...

Comment: if you're ending the "first program" using Ctrl+C to terminate it, then you're actually ending the "process group" which would include the process you `exec`d

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of how fork/exec works. Your problems probably lies elsewhere. Also see [Are child processes created with fork() automatically killed when the parent is killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/395877/608639)

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. I went with what Slava suggested - "nohup" command and it works.